# What's wrong with this PHP code? It's for a WordPress forum plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the wpForo plugin (it's for forums) on my WordPress 4.9 website. When someone uploads an image, it displays a link to the attachment as default. The following code was supplied by the plugin maker and it's supposed to convert the attachment link into the actual image:

```
add_filter('wpforo_content_filter', 'wpforo_default_attachment_image_embed', 11);
function wpforo_default_attachment_image_embed( $content ){
    if( preg_match_all('|<a class=\"wpforo\-default\-attachment\" href\=\"([^\"\']+)\"[^><]*>.+?<\/a>|is', $content, $data, PREG_SET_ORDER) ){
        foreach($data as $array){
            if(isset($array[1])){
                $file = $array[1];
                $e = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
                if( $e == 'jpg' || $e == 'jpeg' || $e == 'png' || $e == 'gif' ){
                    $filename = basename($file);
                    $html = '<a class="wpforo-default-image-attachment" href="' . esc_url($file) . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . esc_url($file) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($filename) . '" title="' . esc_attr($filename) . '" /></a>';
                    $content = str_replace($array[0], $html, $content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Can you see anything wrong with the code? WordPress won't save the code in my functions.php file (child or parent theme), adding the code via FTP crashes the site, and when I tried to put the code in using a third party PHP plugin it said the code causes a fatal error.

I also contacted my theme support and they told me it had something to do with the code or plugin and nothing to do with the theme.

The developer has told me the code works for dozens of other people, but I'm not sure if anyone else on WordPress 4.9 has tried it and if that could be causing an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Turn on WP_DEBUG in your wp-config.php. The warnings you probably see then will tell you whats wrong.

Comment: Hi there! The stackoverflow community enjoys helping out developers achieve their goals, with the premise of helping one's self first. In that regard, have a look at this [link][1] to help you better formulate your question, show your work and help us help you in general. Thanks!


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is the error WordPress gives me when using the code: 
PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in your code on line 3